# get value data into state in react native, how do i get this to work

Tags: react-native

I'm learning React Native and I'm trying to build a simple "questions and answers" form. I have set a value to some text, and when `onPress` is fired, it should get its value to the state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class quest extends Component {
  state = {
    question1: ans1,  //where ans1 is the value onPressed
    question2: ans1,  //where ans3 is the value onPressed
    longitude: 0.3256, //geolocation
    latitude: -0.3589,//geolocation
  }

  onSubmit = () => (
    console.log(this.state)
  )
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <text> What kind of ball is this?</text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans1 value='basketball'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans2 value='football'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans3 value='handball'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <text> What kind of vehicle is this?</text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans1 value='bike'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans2 value='bus'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={//get this value}>
          <text> ans3 value='train'</text>
        <TouchableHighlight />
        <button title='Submit' onPress={onSubmit} />
      </View>
    )
  }       
}
```

Comment: Before you continue learning React Native, have a look at the official docs of React. This scenario can be solved following this part of the docs: [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Also, as you will see in the docs, you will see that you should set the initial state in the constructor. Have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

Comment: Thank you for help and recommending on the official docs of React. It really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    question1: '',
    question2: '',
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.answers}> What kind of ball is this? </Text>

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question1: 'Basketball' })}>
        <Text> Basketball</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question1: 'Football' })}>
        <Text> Football</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question1: 'Volleyball' })}>
        <Text style={styles.answers}> Volleyball</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <Text style={styles.answers}> What kind of vehicle is this? </Text>

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question2: 'Bike' })}>
        <Text> Bike</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question2: 'Bus' })}>
        <Text> Bus</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ question2: 'Train' })}>
        <Text style={styles.answers}> Train</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <Button
        title='Submit'
        onPress={() => console.log(this.state)}
      />

    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 20
  },
  answers: {
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
})
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.Thank you

Comment: @Michaeloforiatta if this solved your issue, maybe mark as an answer, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to save value of the text into state. If yes, then this would work

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({question1: 'bike',})}>
    <text> ans1 value='bike'</text>
<TouchableHighlight/>
```

Comment: This is my first time asking question here, i will do better next time.Thanks anyway :)